# Why is my application displaying two requestPermissionRationales?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-permissions

I am relatively new to programming and have just made a camera app with a preview window held in a surfaceview that requires access to the location and obviously the camera.

However, after showing the `requestPermissionRationale` for a permission and after the user agrees to it, a second `requestPermissionRationale` appears, freezing the camera preview in place. The preview works upon leaving the app and returning. Why is this happening?

I have included the methods that request permissions, my surfaceview class, and the logcat below. `requestUpdates()` includes the code that instantiates the camera and the `surfaceview.request()` is called in `onCreate()`. As shown below, request is called in `onResume()`, and it is also called in `onCreate()`.

```
   private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
 @TargetApi(23)
    protected void requestCam() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("This app requires access to the camera in order to function.",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMPERMISSION_KEY);
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMPERMISSION_KEY);
        }

    }
    @TargetApi(23)
    protected void requestLoc() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            showMessageOKCancel("This app requires access to the location in order to function.",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCPERMISSION_KEY);
                        }

                    });

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCPERMISSION_KEY);
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(23)
    protected void requestBoth() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("This app requires access to both the location and the camera in order to function.",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MULT_KEY);
                           requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMPERMISSION_KEY);
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MULT_KEY);
        }

    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        boolean needLoc = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        boolean needCam = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCPERMISSION_KEY:
                if (needLoc == false && needCam == false) {
                    requestUpdates();
                } else {
                    request();
                }
                break;
            case CAMPERMISSION_KEY:
                if (needCam == false && needLoc == false) {
                    requestUpdates();

                } else {
                    request();
                }
                break;
            case MULT_KEY:
                if (needLoc == false && needCam == false) {
                    requestUpdates();

                } else {
                    request();
                }
        }
    }
    @TargetApi(23)
    public void request() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestUpdates();
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestCam();
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestLoc();
        } else {
            requestBoth();
        }
    }

public void onResume() {
 request();
}
04-13 21:31:33.328 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed
04-13 21:31:33.328 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewSurface(Native Method)
04-13 21:31:33.328 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:738)
04-13 21:31:33.328 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at danielwei816.com.danger.ImageSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(ImageSurfaceView.java:29)
04-13 21:31:33.328 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:634)
04-13 21:31:33.328 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:162)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2281)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
04-13 21:31:33.329 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
04-13 21:31:33.387 30847-30847/danielwei816.com.danger E/Camera: Error 2
```

Comment: Can you update your code, indicating, where you are calling the methods `requestCam()`, `requestLoc()`, `requestBoth()`? Are you doing it on `onResume()` or `onStart()`?

Comment: I updated it. Those methods are facilitated through the request() method, which is called in onResume() and onCreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all there is a logical error in your code. There is mismatch between your permission checking and permission request. Please the comments in the code:

```
   public void request() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestUpdates();
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//You are checking for Location permission grant status but requesting camera permission
            requestCam();
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//You are checking for Camera permission grant status but requesting location permission
            requestLoc();
        } else {
            requestBoth();
        }
    }
```

**The reason why you see two rationale as follows:**

You are requesting the permission in `onResume()`.

When you request for permission, Android OS internally launches a new Activity to show the permission dialog and covers your current Activity. When user grants the permission, your activity comes to foreground and `onResume()` will be called. As a result you will see another rationale

You can avoid it by checking and requesting (if necessary) the permissions in `onCreate()` only and trigger request to access camera only after permissions has been granted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try implementing this way (i.e., use single statement to request permissions)**

```
@TargetApi(23)
protected void requestBoth() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        showMessageOKCancel("This app requires access to both the location and the camera in order to function.",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MULT_KEY);
                       // requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMPERMISSION_KEY);
                    }
                });

    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MULT_KEY);
    }

}
```